# Why does tmap render 80 times faster than ggplot2? [Plotting shapefiles in R with ggplot2::geom_sf(), using XQuartz/X11 graphics device on macOS]

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, xquartz

**Update/Edit/Reprex**: Rendering the same spatial data with the same graphics device takes 1 second with `tmap` versus 80 seconds with `ggplot2`, even though the `tmap` plot's R object is 80x larger in size. Difference in internals and/or implementation btw. packages & graphics device?

```
library(ggplot2); library(sf); 
library(tmap); library(tidyverse)
library(here) # project directory

data(World) # sf object from tmap; Provides Africa polygon

# 'd' data pulled from acleddata.com/data, restricted to Aug 18 2017  - Aug 18 2018, Region: N/S/E/W/Middle Africa only
d <- read.csv(here('2017-08-18-2018-08-18-Eastern_Africa-Middle_Africa-Northern_Africa-Southern_Africa-Western_Africa.csv'))
dsf <- st_as_sf(d, coords = c('longitude', 'latitude'), crs = 4326)
```

Data used:

1. 'World' shapefile data from the `tmap` package itself, and
2. [acleddata.com/data](http://acleddata.com/data), ACLED conflict events restricted to Africa between August 18 2017 and August 18 2018 (7.8 MB .csv; these filters:)

[image: data used]

Plot rendering:

```
# ggplot2; build plot, assign to object
dev.cur()   # RStudioGD on macOS: quartz
system.time(p <- ggplot(World %>% filter(continent == 'Africa')) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  geom_sf(data = dsf, aes(fill = event_type, 
              color = event_type)) + 
  ggthemes::theme_tufte() + 
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(.1, 'cm'),
        legend.title = element_blank()))
   # user  system elapsed 
   # 0.016   0.001   0.017 

object.size(p)
# 175312 bytes

# render
system.time(print(p))
# user  system elapsed 
# 84.755   0.432  85.418  # Note over 80 seconds
```

[image: ggplot2 png]

```
# tmap; build plot, assign to object
tmap_mode('plot')
system.time(tm <- tm_shape(World, filter = 
                        (World$continent == 'Africa')) + 
               tm_polygons(group = 'Countries') +
               tm_shape(dsf) + 
               tm_dots(col = 'event_type', group = 'event_type'))
    # user  system elapsed 
    # 0.000   0.000   0.001 

object.size(tm)
# 14331968 bytes   # This is 80x ggplot2 plot's object size
                   # 14331968/175312 = 81.75121
# render
dev.cur()    # RStudioGD on macOS: quartz
system.time(print(tm))
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.438   0.038   1.484   # Note 1 second
```

[image: tmap png]

---

[Previous inquiry into geom_sf() & graphics devices, without the tmap comparison:]

TL;DR:

I am trying to speed up my plotting speed by switching graphics devices to *X11* since my default *Quartz* graphics device is slow. After downloading XQuartz to connect to the X11 graphics device and calling `grDevices::X11()`, I don't understand the errors I'm getting.

```
X11(type = "cairo")
# Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  : 
                    #   unable to start device X11
                    # In addition: Warning message:
                    #   In X11() : unable to open connection to X11 display 'cairo'
#> Warning in X11(type = "cairo"): unable to open connection to X11 display ''
```

And when I call R from a XQuartz.app terminal on macOS instead, the error message is slightly different:

```
X11(type = "cairo")
#> Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize, : unable to start device X11cairo
```

End TL;DR

Broader Context:

Plotting large shapefiles with `ggplot2::geom_sf()`, the quartz graphics device used in macOS plots considerably slower than other devices, and while this larger performance issue is being resolved, I want to change my device from Quartz to X11.

I downloaded XQuartz, following advice from the [RStudio forums](https://community.rstudio.com/t/ggplot2-geom-sf-performance/3251), but my code doesn't successfully call X11, even when I launch R from XQuartz.

Proof, using the same data as the RStudio forum poster:

```
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.3
library(ggplot2)
tmpzip <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
download.file("https://github.com/bcgov/bcmaps.rdata/blob/master/data-raw/ecoregions/ecoregions.zip?raw=true", destfile = tmpzip)
gdb_path <- unzip(tmpzip, exdir = tempdir())
ecoregions <- sf::read_sf(dirname(gdb_path[1]))

## Create ggplot2 object
ecoregions_gg <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = ecoregions)

# Running quartz device - default macOS
system.time(print(ecoregions_gg))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#> 128.980   0.774 130.375

### ^ Note two full minutes!
```

[image: Shapefile]

This default device runs for an unusually long 129 seconds given the size.
X11 should run faster according to the RStudio forum. A test on a (granted, faster) Windows 7 machine (32 GB RAM, 3.60 GHz) using its default graphics device (not Quartz), yielded:

```
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    2.16    2.24    4.46

###  ^Only two seconds
```

While people are troubleshooting the general geom_sf / Quartz performance problems ([Github Issue 1](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2655), [Github Issue 2](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2718)), how can I use my XQuartz install to run X11 and speed up my shapefile plotting?

Comment: I don't get the error you're getting with `X11(type = "cairo")`. Are you sure you have x11 /XQuartz installed?

Comment: As far as I know yes. Perhaps there's some trouble linking it to R, but I do have XQuartz installed, and I've reinstalled as well. As I mention above I get this error from inside RStudio, but also when I launch a terminal within XQuartz.app, run R, and then call base::capabilities(), which recognizes X11.

Comment: Could you modify the example so it uses a data file that is publicly available? We don't have `ggplot2vstmap/2017-08-18-2018-08-18-Eastern_Africa-Middle_Africa-Northern_Africa-Southern_Africa-Western_Africa.csv`.

Comment: Thanks, it was in my code block but I should have pulled it out to be clearer. I've fixed that and also added a screenshot of how the page looks when you pull the .csv, which should be 7.8 MB with those filters

Comment: Another way of plotting shape files is to use `polygon` from base and looping through the shape-sturcture manually. On a Mac it is still not blazingly fast, but acceptable (e.g. under a minute for all US counties in high resolution).

Comment: I had a similar observation once plotting color gradients and some dots on a rectangular grid for many timepoints to generate a movie from it: base plots are super fast compared to ggplot (and likely tmap as well).
In most cases, this does not matter, but in cases where ggplot gets slow or speed is an issue, switching to other plotting options is a sensible option

Comment: `killall` on Quartz then with X11 running try opening an X11 device in R by typing X11() or X11(type = "cairo"). If the device opens successfully, you should be able to plot using the X11 device.

Answer (score 2):

several things you may want to consider regarding rendering the same spatial data iwth the same graphics device:

1. tmap and ggplot use different internal data structures. tmap uses the sf package which uses the simple features format. ggplot2 uses geom_sf() function that converts spatial data into data frame. this can lead to different performance.
2. tmap and ggplot2 have different approaches to rendering spatial data. tmap uses a highly optimized rendering engine designed for thematic mapping. it uses techniques like rasterization and map tiling to efficiently render. ggplot2 is general purpose.
3. graphics device can also affect rendering performance.

if you want to improve perofrmance of shapefile plotting in ggplot2, consider these:

1. simplify gemoetry of shapefile using the sf package's st_simplify(). this will reduce number of vertices
2. limit number of features